# Issue with getting options from Command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, getopt

OK, I know about `getopt`.

So, let's say if I want to have to options (e.g. `a`,`b`), I would do a `getopt("a:b:")` and
something like `php myscript.php -a someAvalue -b someBvalue` would be perfectly recogniseable with the option values stored as they should.

Now what if I wanted to be able to recognise the most common type of syntax and still get `getopt` to work :

```
php myscript.php somefile.txt -a someAvalue -b someBvalue
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the command line parameters using variable: $argv[]

Comment: Remember that it's only available when `PHP_SAPI === 'cli'`

Comment: Yep, that's true. BUT : when using the above syntax, then `getopt` breaks. Any ideas?